# Excel formula to match store category name & ID

Tags: excel, magento

I have a Magento store which contains over 2500 categories. I have so many categories because I have assigned each unique product its own category. Each unique product requires its own category because there will be many identical product listings from separate suppliers

Please view the below url for clarity:
http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products/full-product-list/p-products/potassium-nitrate.html

The above url shows how I have created a category named "Potassium nitrate", I have then assigned identical products to that category.

I have a csv excel sheet containing all my unique chemical compounds which are displayed on my website. Within that sheet I have also included all my store category names & ID's.

I am requiring a simple excel formula that will go through each product, comparing its name to the category name (the names in both areas should be identical), if a match is found, the category ID for that product will be inserted into the "Category ID" column on the product sheet. I would also like to assign 3 categories to each product by default (products, full product list & all products) categories.

Here's my excel sheet download page. Please take a look & see if you can help me out with the matching.

http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/Shared/matchingCategories.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like below

```
Product Name    category_ids
Abietic acid    332
Acacia          328
```

write below statement in column B at B2 location

`=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$2640,2,FALSE)`

Apply this for all cells...

**Note**

Wherever you find `#N/A`, it means that respective `Product Name` is not present in `Store Category Name`. Hope it clears...

### Update 1

If you want to print `3294297` instead of `#N/A` use below

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$2640,2,FALSE)),3294297,VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$2640,2,FALSE))`

### Update 2

If you want to print `No Match` instead of `#N/A` use below

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$2640,2,FALSE)),"No Match",VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$2640,2,FALSE))`

### Good Luck!!!

Comment: Cheers, I'll check it out & let you know my result :)

Comment: Ok it worked nicely, but how would I change the "#N/A" to something like "No Match"? Would be helpful when creating categories for the ones which don't have a match. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this formula on **Column B**

```
=LOOKUP(A2,C:C,D:D)
```

Above formula requires columns in ascending order.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

### Result

```
Product Name         category_ids  
Abietic acid             332   
Acacia                   328   
Acenaphthene             329   
Acenaphthoquinone        330   
Acenaphthylene           671   
Acephate                 672
```

Comment: Abietic acid is there, why you have `#N/A`??

Comment: YOUR CODE FAILS.... also `Acetarsol` is not there in `Store Category Name` but your code says `679`  which is nothing BUT PREVIOUS VALUE...

Comment: @FahimParkar: i have updated the answer.. earlier am in assumption that columns are in ascending order.. but unfortunately not.